# Programmatically register broadcast receiver which will fire if app closed

Tags: android

Is is possible to programmatically registerReceiver() which will be called even if app process closed, like when it is specified in manifest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, sorry. `registerReceiver()` will only work while your app's process is running.